# Java ^ operator

Tags: java, operators

Java programming.

```
int i = 0;
int j = 1;
str.charAt(i) ^ str2.charAt(j)
```

What does mean ^ operator in java? And what is this operator reverse operation?
example 
w ^ . = 121
T ^ W = 35

Comment: The `^` operation can be reversed by re-applying itself: `x^n ^n == x`

Answer (score 4):

The bitwise `^` operator performs a bitwise exclusive OR operation.

Applied, this does:

```
false ^ false = false
false ^ true = true
true ^ false = true
true ^ true = false
```

When it comes to integer varibles (including the type `char`) the numbers are converted to their binary representation and then the operator takes place. For example:

```
3 ^ 5 = 011 ^ 101 = 110 = 6
```

Answer (score 0):

`^` indicates Binary `XOR` Operator copies the bit if it is set in one operand but not both.

Truth Table For XOR

[image]